# Does Russia export anything that isn't widely available elsewhere?

Tags: international-trade, monopoly, russia

Some countries produce items for which there is no easy substitute.

For example [Taiwan](https://tecvalue.com/which-country-produces-the-most-number-of-chips) produces 53% of the world's [semiconductors](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2021/02/25/why-is-there-a-shortage-of-semiconductors).

Is there any product(s)/service(s) for which Russia is a [monopolist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopolist) (the only supplier) or oligopolist (one of a small number of suppliers)?

Comment: Maybe qualify (although I think other space companies manage to find engines elsewhere, so probably doesn't count): https://www.reuters.com/world/russia-halts-deliveries-rocket-engines-us-2022-03-03/

Comment: Natural gas in Europe. Pretty much no short term alternative. Fortunately, also not for Russia who relies heavily on gas exports, which is why gas keeps flowing to Europe. Look at the [largest](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_of_Russia) companies in Russia. Essentially oil (easier to substitute), gas, metals and mining and finance. The rest, mostly non russian companies (foreign subsidiaries).